# how to create virtualhosts nginx for docker containers after their start

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy, portainer

I have portainer. There are customized templates that create different web servers. There is a ningx reverse proxy that is installed on the host. How can I configure the automatic creation of a virtual ningx host for new docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

- `/etc/nginx/conf.d` should be `volume`
- create new virtualhost (in volume directory)
- update service/stack (for `swarm` mode) or just restart container